# How to write a one-liner to remove files specified by a list (maybe contained by a file)

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file containing a list of targeted files that I want to remove (separated by newline).

For example, list.txt:

```
    1/abc.txt
    1/2/bcd.txt
    3/efg.txt
    ...
```

How can I write a one-liner in shell to remove those files?

I tried `cat list.txt|xargs -0 rm`, but get `:File name too long`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```bash
xargs -d '\n' -a list.txt -I {} rm -- {}
```

The explanation of the arguments:

```bash
man xargs
...
-a file, --arg-file=file
              Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use this option, stdin remains unchanged when commands are run.  Otherwise, stdin is redirected from /dev/null.

--delimiter=delim, -d delim
              Input items are terminated by the specified character.  The specified delimiter may be a single character, a C-style character escape such as \n, or an octal or hexadecimal
              escape  code.  Octal and hexadecimal escape codes are understood as for the printf command.   Multibyte characters are not supported.  When processing the input, quotes and
              backslash are not special; every character in the input is taken literally.  The -d option disables any end-of-file string, which is treated like any other  argument.   You
              can use this option when the input consists of simply newline-separated items, although it is almost always better to design your program to use --null where this is possi‐
              ble.
-I replace-str
              Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the  separator
              is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

Comment: Good one!  By the way, what does the `{}` mean? (for `-I {} rm -- {}`)

Comment: You could image that `{}` is a placeholder of the file in the list.txt, so you could use other Unix commands to process the file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved by adding `tr '\n' '\0'`, thus the newline symbol can be transformed to `NUL`, which `xargs -0` can take as separator.

The one-liner:

`cat list.txt|tr '\n' '\0'|xargs -0 rm`

Comment: May I suggest that you also remove the unnecessary `cat` in your answer?

Comment: Here my `cat list.txt` is just a simple placeholder, which represents a stdin data flow. Actually, the data source comes from another script that dynamically generates newline spaced content and pipes to stdout.   Thus I use `cat` to keep some data flow programming style.